# Right click on Dock icons in Mission Control

Tags: dock, mission-control

When I right click on an icon in the Dock, I get a menu as usual (New Window, Options, Quit, etc.). When I right click an an icon in the Dock in Mission Control nothing happens.

**How can I enable the right-click menu for Dock app icons while in Mission control?**

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you cannot right click a Dock icon while in Mission Control.

Comment: Perhaps there is a hack/interface app or some sort?

Comment: this is still true in November 2021 (9 years after this question first posted). Right clicking a dock icon in mission control still does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Clicking and holding on the dock icon will open the context menu, though it will also dismiss Mission Control at the same time (but that still saves you the step of having to dismiss Mission Control yourself first).

Comment: it's unclear what this answer is trying to say, because as of November 2021, clicking and holding a dock icon while in Mission Control certainly does *not* open any menus.

Comment: Yeah, my answer no longer seems to be true (just tried it on 11.6 Big Sur). The current version of macOS at the time the question was asked was 10.8 Mountain Lion; obviously, the behavior has changed since then and this no longer works.